# how to create a string literal as a function argument via string concatenation in c

Tags: c, string, concatenation, argument-passing, literals

I need to pass a string literal to a function

```
myfunction("arg1" DEF_CHAR "arg1");
```

now part of that constructed string literal needs to be a function return

```
stmp = createString();
myfunction("arg1" stmp "arg2"); //oh that doesn't work either
```

is there any way to do this in one line?

```
myfunction("arg1" createString() "arg2"); //what instead?
```

NOTE: C only please.

My goal is to avoid initializing a new char array for this =/

Comment: This is completely impossible. If a string is created at run-time it is not a string literal by definition.

Comment: String literal concatenation is only really there because long strings are common and it would be a pain in the but to define them without it.  You can do what you want in one messy line, but not without allocating memory for it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot build string literal at runtime, but you can create the string, like this:

```
char param[BIG_ENOUGH];

strcpy(param, "arg1");
strcat(param, createString());
strcat(param, "arg2");
myfunction(param);
```

Comment: In fact the reason that `strcpy()` and `strcat()` return a pointer to the destination string is for precisely this situation - it lets you do `myfunction(strcat(strcat(strcpy(param, "arg1"), createstring()), "arg2"))`

Answer (score 2):

```
char buffer[1024] = {0};
//initialize buffer with 0 
//tweak length according to your needs

strcat(buffer, "arg1");
strcat(buffer, createString()); //string should be null ternimated
strcat(buffer, "arg2");

myfunction(buffer);
```

Answer (score 2):

C does not support dynamic strings, so what you're attempting is impossible.  The return value from your createString() function is a variable, not a literal, so you can't concatenate it with other literals.  That being said, if it's really important to you to have this on one line, you can create a helper function to facilitate this, something like the following:

```
char * my_formatter( const char * format, ... )
{
...
}

myfunction(my_formatter("arg1%sarg2", createString()));
```

There are some memory management and thread saftey issues with this approach, however.

Answer (score 1):

You need to make a character array for this; only string literals are concatenated by the compiler.

Answer (score 0):

Nope.  No way to do this in pure C without allocating a new buffer to concatenate the strings.